# Url routing for php with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I have a easy question but don't do this. My site url is localhost/Project/Controller/Method but I want to localhost/Project/method. my htaccess as follows;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/]+)$(/?) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What "Controller" should you use if it is omitted? Btw, `$` in a regex is an "end of string" anchor, so does not make sense unescaped in the middle of the regex.

Comment: Are you using  your own mvc or any other mvc ?

Comment: @w3d controller is my controller name and method is method name.

Comment: @user7282 own custom mvc

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use a URL like `localhost/Project/method` (which doesn't state a _controller_), but your URLs presumably need to be of the form `localhost/Project/Controller/Method` (ie. _with_ a stated controller) then what _controller_ do you want to use when it is omitted in the URL?

Comment: @w3d yes my url form in my mvc platform localhost/Project/Controller/Method, but I set the haccess file.My new url when a link will appear in the section, it should be localhost/Project/method

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?action=$1/$2/$3 [L] (this works for module/controller/method)

Comment: @pregmatch This code did not work. My link in a href="localhost/Project/Controller/Method" isn't it right. My file structure        Project(app(controller(Project(Method))-models()-views())-index.php-htaccess)  *Project=Controller Name  * Method=Methods Name of control

Comment: i can only guess. how your index.php looks like?

Comment: <code> ob_start();
Session::init();
error_reporting(0);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function __autoload($className) {
    include_once 'system/libs/' . $className . '.php';
}<code>

Comment: Well, your current `RewriteRule` should already be capturing requests for `localhost/Project/method`, just as it does for `localhost/Project/Controller/Method`, although (as mentioned above) you need to fix the `RewriteRule` pattern and remove the trailing `(/?)`.

Comment: yes you are right @w3d, but It did not matter what I did.

Comment: `My link in a href="localhost/Project/Controller/Method"` - If you want to change your URLs to `localhost/Project/Method`, then you need to change this in your on page links. Unless I've misunderstood, this isn't something you do only in .htaccess.